# python - checking several variables against list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that needs to run if any of the variables match some strings.
The code seems long and not very pythonic:

```
if candidate_job_title in ('ERROR', 'NOT AVAILABLE') or candidate_company in ('ERROR', 'NOT AVAILABLE') or candidate_location in ('ERROR', 'NOT AVAILABLE'):  
# do something
```

the best I could come up with is this, is there anything else I can do to make it more readable?

```
if any (v in ('ERROR', 'NOT AVAILABLE') for v in (candidate_job_title, candidate_company, candidate_location):
# do something
```

Comment: In your first code sample, you mentioned candidate_company twice. I think one of them should be candidate_location.

Comment: Do all candidate properties need to be checked against the same set of strings?

Comment: no, only a subset of all candidate properties need to be checked.

Comment: No, I meant do you always need to check against ('ERROR', 'NOT AVAILABLE') only? Or can there be any other string for location and something else for company?

Comment: ok, got you now. No, always the same set of strings.

Comment: Then I think we can't beat aguest's solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If these values are hashable you can use set intersection:

```
if {candidate_job_title, candidate_company, candidate_location} & {'ERROR', 'NOT AVAILABLE'}:
    ...
```